# The question already exists and well-received but has limited/non-working answer(s). How to proceed?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, duplicate-questions

It is pretty clear that if a question already exist, then it should not be asked again otherwise it will be marked as duplicate.

However, I often bump into 'aged' questions which have a considerable amount of upvotes and views but has less answer(s) (sometimes only one) that either doesn't work or isn't always appropriate solution (but only a workaround). Since the answer(s) does not work, I think of asking a new question -which in fact is not allowed (as it would be marked duplicate). This puts me in a fix.

How to proceed in such scenarios where I have discovered a well-received question that has very limited, non-working answers/workarounds?

I just don't want to unnecessarily edit, comment on such questions to make them active. I want a mechanism to draw people's attention on that specific question for the answer. Or is there any other better way round?

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).

Answer (score 5):

There is a mechanism you can use which is placing a bounty on it.

[image]

If you feel any of the answers are unclear you could also try to comment on them and ask for clarifiction.

If the answers simply don't work I personally don't see an issue with raising a new question where you explain that you've tried to use the solution proposed in an already existing answer and provide details about how or why it doesn't work for you. You should provide a clear [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows that the solution does not work. Such a question should not be closed as a duplicate in my opinion. Technology and environments change and previous answers can stop working over time.

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that in question that I also don't want to use bounty--Placing bounty is a good idea for users who has a suitable high rep..Users like me that are still in process of increasing and earning reps might hesitate to use bounty often. Yes, I can comment - but that might not the optimal case according to me. I can ask question for sure - but then this [issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261272/339295) can arise.

Comment: @KaranDesai Well, I do feel that if you can present a good MCVE showing that an answer doesn't work it could warrant posting a new question but opinions will vary. Short of commenting or placing bounties (which I'm aware is a high threshold for newer users) I don't know of any other mechanism.